# using (Offset & Resize) instead of (Intersect),raising Run-time error '1004':Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba, offset

on below code, I am using `Intersect` to select matching the specific condition instead of selecting the Entire Row.
as a learning purpose, I tried to use (Offset & Resize) instead of (Intersect), But it raising

> Run-time error '1004':Application-defined or object-defined error

my values found on `range A:AF`
In advance grateful for useful comments and answer.

```
Sub Union_Test()
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Dim lastR As Long: lastR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Dim cel As Range, rng As Range, uRng As Range

 Set rng = ws.Range("V3:V" & lastR)
    For Each cel In rng
     If cel.value = "Yes" Then
        If uRng Is Nothing Then
            Set uRng = cel
        Else
            Set uRng = Union(uRng, cel)
        End If
     End If
  Next cel
'If Not uRng Is Nothing Then Intersect(uRng.EntireRow, ws.UsedRange).Select 'this works perfectly
 If Not uRng Is Nothing Then uRng.Offset(, -21).Resize(, 32).Select  'This raising error
End Sub
```

Comment: `Resize(, 32)` doesn't seem to work with a multi-area range such as `"A3:A4, A6"`.

Comment: @BigBen ,It works now ,Kindly see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the code to add Offset and resize to the value of `Urng` itself after `IF Condtion`,Then it works.

```
Sub Union_Test()
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Dim lastR As Long: lastR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Dim cel As Range, rng As Range, uRng As Range

 Set rng = ws.Range("V3:V" & lastR)
    For Each cel In rng
     If cel.value = "Yes" Then
        If uRng Is Nothing Then
            Set uRng = cel.Offset(, -21).Resize(, 32)
        Else
            Set uRng = Union(uRng, cel.Offset(, -21).Resize(, 32))
        End If
     End If
  Next cel
If Not uRng Is Nothing Then uRng.Select    'Now This works
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, creating `rng` spanning from columns A to AF, then looping over its `.Rows`.

```
Set rng = ws.Range("A3:AF" & lastR)

Dim rw As Range
For Each rw in rng.Rows
    If rw.Range("V1").Value = "Yes" Then 'This refers to V3, V4, V5, etc.
        If uRng Is Nothing Then
            Set uRng = rw
        Else
            Set uRng = Union(uRng, rw)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I thought `("V1")` is a typo , But after trying your code , It works as supposed

Comment: Right. So basically `A1` refers to the first cell *in that row*, that row being A3:AF3. So `V1` actually corresponds to cell V3 on the sheet. Another option instead of `Range("V1")` is `Cells(1, 22)`. If confused, try `? Range("A3:AF3").Range("V1").Address`, which returns `$V$3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain what you want using your code (from the question), only replacing of its last line:

```
If Not uRng Is Nothing Then uRng.Offset(, -21).Resize(, 32).Select
```

which does not work in discontinuous ranges, with:

```
If Not uRng Is Nothing Then Intersect(uRng.EntireRow, ws.Range("A:AF")).Select
```

It is better (more efficient) to build a `Union` range from a cell per row, in a single column. For large such ranges (in terms of columns, too) it consumes more Excel resources...

Comment: Thanks and I learned from your advice as already done on my own answer 

Comment: @Waleed No doubt, from this point of view. I only wanted emphasizing that there may be more solutions, but the best approach is to choose the optimum one, taking in consideration more aspects. Nobody can say that he know everything about programming in any language. In my case, for instance, what I thought that what I yesterday was the best solution, has been proved that an even better solution exists... It is good to experiment and learn. But the global approach should also involve a kind of efficiency analysis, from many points of view...